# How do I manage an external Windows application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

What is the best way to manage an external windows application in C# (or .NET)?

So far my I've been able to launch a process using System.Diagnostics.Process, however this simply allows me to launch/kill a process. (from what I've gathered)

I noticed System.Diagnostics.Process has a CloseMainWindow() routine which will send a request to a process' window. Can I use this Process class to send different messages? (if so, can anyone point me in direction of where I can learn about these windows messages)

I need to be able to manage an external program and manipulate it the following ways:
1) Launch
2) Kill Process
3) Show Application (Fullscreen and in taskbar)
4) Hide Application (Fullscreen and in taskbar)

Further details:
Windows 7, Restricted to .Net 3.5 Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use interop and use SendMessage to do all of your functionality.  See this: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a message to that window. Take a look at `SendMessage` . The messages you need are `SW_MINIMIZE`,`SW_RESTORE` and `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some Win32 P/Invoke stuff to send window messages in order to do what you want.

See this code sample on [ShowWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ShowWindow) or [SendMessage](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html) which tells an external window to show or hide itself. You'll first need to get the window handle you want with [FindWindowEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can do all you want in different ways, once you start the process yourself or you find it in the list of running processes, using classes or methods of `System.Diagnostics.Process`, then you can follow different options...

for example consider that once you have this handle: `Process.MainWindowHandle` you can send messages to that handle, with `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` and this allows you to do very very much; or you can use PInvoke APIs like `SetWindowPos` or `ShowWindow` or `SetWindowLong` and do basically really everything...

see this for example:

[How to use the ShowWindow API to hide and show a form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/12d1840d-e894-4097-ae41-46e69bb5b5c0/)

I can send you more links but won't like to refer to the whole MSDN ;-)